# Parse a json object shows undefined

Tags: json, react-native, parsing

I was using [OMDBapi](http://www.omdbapi.com/) to get the details of different movies. I successfully fetched the result and it returns a json object like this;

```
{"Title":"WWA: The Inception","Year":"2001","Rated":"N/A","Released":"26 Oct 2001","Runtime":"N/A","Genre":"Action, Sport","Director":"N/A","Writer":"Jeremy Borash","Actors":"Bret Hart, Jeff Jarrett, Brian James, David Heath","Plot":"N/A","Language":"English","Country":"Australia","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTEyNGJjMTMtZjZhZC00ODFkLWIyYzktN2JjMTcwMmY5MDJlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDkwMzY5NjQ@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"6.0/10"}],"Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"6.0","imdbVotes":"22","imdbID":"tt0311992","Type":"movie","DVD":"N/A","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
```

Note that we get this type of object from the api if we want to get a particular movie details and that is what i was doing. Now to show the different details to a user, i started parsing this JSON object which works fine but when i try to get the value of the `Value` key present inside the `Ratings` key, it returns undefined.

I am working with react-native. After getting the data, i stored it inside the state, named it as `details`. Then to get it;

```
this.state.details.Title //if i wanted to get the Title and it works fine.
```

Then for `Value` inside `Ratings`;

```
this.state.details.Ratings[0].Value
```

But it returns undefined.

Also note that this works fine in pure Javascript as i parsed the dict in the browser console in the same way and it returned the correct value.

Here is more code;

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${this.props.navigation.getParam('i')}&apikey=******`) // where this.props.navigation.getParam('i') is the omdbid of the movie
    const result = await response.json()
    this.setState({details: result})
    
}
```

Here is error log;

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.details.Ratings[0]')
```

Comment: Could u share the code snipper that does what u explained in your question?

Comment: I already shared it. The last line in my question is giving the error. As the said i am able to parse all the other keys. Only this one is giving the error.

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli i added the code also.

Comment: And you're testing with **Exact same URL** you posted its result in your question?

Comment: Yes from the same url

Comment: Can you log the result? What's inside of it?

Comment: Added error log to the question.

Comment: Error log is not relevant. Can you log what variable `result` contains? 

`const result = await response.json()

// add logging here
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely trying to access state object before `fetch` has done it's job .... it's an async op ... so you should make sure your `data` is ready before rendering...

```
  if (this.state.details) {
    // start rendering...
  }
```

**More Explanation**

your `setState` function should be executed right after `fetch` has finished its job, and since it's an **async** operation, it's going to take **some time** ...During **that time**, `render` function is executed with no `state.details` --> causing your issue ...

That's why you should check for `state` before rendering ... besides, the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) trick **Silversky Technology** mentioned in his answer

Comment: Man, you're getting `undefined is not an object` error! ... which means `details` object does not even exist

Comment: You were right. It worked but can you please explain the things going there. Because i was able to get all the other values, even the values which come after it.

Answer (score 1):

If the value property you are accessing from the object might be not available for all the movies in the data you are getting from API response so it might cause you to error when accessing key from undefined objects.

To overcome the issue there is a way, you can try a fix as below:

```
this.state.details.Ratings[0]?.Value
```

The ? symbol lets the javascript not give an error when the value key not available in the object. it will make the accessing of property optional.

Comment: I tried for a number of movies, also for the movies which have these values but it still shows the same error.

Comment: @Irfanwani are you mapping the data you received from the API response?

Comment: Why should i map that. That is a single  object and i am trying to get the value of different keys using dot notation and it works fine for all other keys. I also tried map for this particular key but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Irfanwani Can you try with the console.log(this.state.details.Ratings[0]) to check whether the data logging or not ?

Answer (score 0):

When storing objects in states it often causes problems as you are doing in line

```
this.setState({details: result})
```

Save result after strigifying it like

```
JSON.stringify(result)
this.setState({details: result})
```

Then when fetching form state, parse it back to object by

```
var result = JSON.parse(this.state.details)
```

Then you should be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

You can access Ratings[0].Value by

```
this.state.details.Ratings && this.state.details.Ratings[0].Value
```

like,

```
  <Text> {this.state.details.Ratings && this.state.details.Ratings[0].Value} </Text>
```